# Angularjs: Achieve Same Structure for Service as Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, plunker

I am playing with `angularjs` `services` and `factories`. I have created a factory called `BookFactory` as follows:

```
// Code goes here

app
  .factory('BootFactory', function() {
    var bookFactory;

    function add() {

    }

    function remove() {

    }

    function getAll() {

    }
    bookFactory = {
      add: add,
      remove: remove,
      getAll: getAll
    }
    return bookFactory;

  });
```

And a `BookService` as follows:

```
app.service('BookService', function() {

        var bookService;

        function add() {

        }

        function remove() {

        }

        function getAll() {

        }

        /*
        It throws:
        Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

        How can I achieve the same structure with the services which I have used in factories.

        this = {
          add: add,
          remove: remove,
          getAll: getAll
        };

        */

        //Do I have to add all methods like this
        this.add=add;
        this.remove=remove;
        this.getAll=getgAll;

        //Or there's any other better way to achieve it

      });
```

What I want to do is I want to keep the keep the structure consistent i.e.  I want want something like this for both factory and services:

```
bookFactory = {
          add: add,
          remove: remove,
          getAll: getAll
        }
```

In case of factory it works fine. But in case of service I can not do so. cause service works with `this` and I can not do this:

```
/*
            It throws:
            Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

            How can I achieve the same structure with the services which I have used in factories.

            this = {
              add: add,
              remove: remove,
              getAll: getAll
            };

            */
```

What I am thinking to do is:

```
//Do I have to add all methods like this
            this.add=add;
            this.remove=remove;
            this.getAll=getgAll;

            //Or there's any other better way to achieve it
```

Is there any better way to do so? Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0fhnTQUOxHRBC844yJX?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create bookService like as-

```
app.service('BookService', function() {
    return {
          add:add,
          remove:remove,
          getAll:getAll
        };

    function add() {

        }

        function remove() {

        }

        function getAll() {

        }

  });
```

Comment: We should not do return anything with the service function as it is the constructor function.

Comment: Yeap, correct. A service is a constructor function, however, that doesn’t prevent us from doing additional work and return object literals. In fact, constructor functions in JavaScript can return whatever they want. So we can take our service code and write it in a way that it basically does the exact same thing as our factory

Comment: @HiteshKumar Read this please- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
app.service('BookService', function() {
    function add() {

    }

    function remove() {

    }

    function getAll() {

    }

    var bookService = {
      add: add,
      remove: remove,
      getAll: getAll
    };

    return bookService;
  });
```

Angular doesn't really care what your service returns. Factory vs Service is only about how it gets invoked, factory is called like this: factory() and service like this: new service(). In JS, the constructor can return anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Factories and services are just two slightly different ways to create a service-object instance.

The factory function returns the instance itself.

The service function is a constructor function and gets used with `new` (or something like it) to create the instance. Constructor functions in JS can return the object instance that was instantiated directly (instead of the default `this`, [read more](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2522-providing-a-return-value-in-a-javascript-constructor.htm)).

This should let you do this:

```
  .service('BookService', function() {
    var bookService;

    function add() {}

    function remove() {}

    function getAll() {}

    bookService = {
      add: add,
      remove: remove,
      getAll: getAll
    }
    return bookService;
  })
```

So yes, `factory` and `service` can function the exact same way because of this JS quirk.

I don't really know why you want to have the same recipe for both, since semantically they are doing the same, why not just create all services using a particular one in that case?